# OK or ACCEPTED symbol in HTML?

Tags: html, symbols

Can somebody please help me, I want to put the "OK" symbol throw HTML not as image, by saying "OK" symbol I mean this symbol (http://awesomescreenshot.com/0272k1125)
Can somebody help me and tell me what code is this in html please ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `<input type="button" />` with some custom CSS

Comment: oh thanks everyone, I found it now here "http://tntluoma.com/sidebars/codes/" , the code in html is &#10004;

Comment: @Rob: View source doesn't work here, as it's implemented on that page with an image.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is a Unicode character that looks like a check mark: `✓`

To use it in HTML, you'll probably want to escape it. The code looks like this:

```html
&#10003; <!-- in decimal -->
&#x2713; <!-- in hex     -->
```

There is also a "heavier" (bold) version of this same symbol: `✔`

Again, the escapes are:

```html
&#10004; <!-- in decimal -->
&#x2714; <!-- in hex     -->
```

But definitely pay attention to the concerns expressed by the other answers regarding the inclusion of this character with the font(s) you're intending to use, and the possibility that the character may not display correctly on client machines.

Comment: see for using it in pseudo css classes (e.g. `content`): https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/heavy-check-mark/

Answer (score 6):

As I understand, you want to put the Unicode CHECK MARK (U+2713) symbol on your page. However, I'm not fully sure that this character is implemented in most fonts, so it is possible that the character will not appear on some client browsers.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the CHECK MARK character, it’s U+2713. The way to enter it depends on your authoring environment; the character reference `&#x2173;` can be used instead, but it reduces source legibility.

The CHECK MARK character is present in many fonts, but not all. Its [font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/fontsupport.htm) does not include any font that is available in Windows PCs, unless Microsoft Office has been installed. In addition to this primary concern, some browsers may fail to display the character even if it is available in some font; [using CSS you can increase the odds](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

The two-letter abbreviation “OK” works much more reliably. Though originally an English abbreviation of obscure origin, it is widely recognized. The CHECK MARK is more questionable, even though people usually know it from web page forms where it appears in checked checkboxes. But it’s not really universal; when I was at school, a symbol like CHECK MARK indicated an error, not acceptance.